# Is it possible to have dividends included in profits and losses with TD Ameritrade's thinkorswim?

Tags: thinkorswim

I'm using OnDemand and have not found a section where I can see the amount I'd have earned in dividends.

---

A TD Ameritrade support person told me that neither the paper money nor OnDemand accounts show this.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have evaluated a long trade that spanned an ex-dividend and it did not include the dividend.  If you haven't done this, determine the P&L of the trade and see if the dividend was included.

If not, call tech support at TD Ameritrade for assistance.